# Foreign key massacre: How many tables, Winston?

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a feature related to defining insurance policies.

There's table of Provisions that have names and IDs. Anything called an "ID" here is a surrogate key in a table.

We then have Forms, FormBenefits, and Riders. Those are very different kinds of things, each in its own table, but each can have selected provisions. All the provisions are defined in the same table and each one may be selected for any Form/FormBenefit/Rider, at the discretion of the insurance industry lifers who use the tool I'm working on.

When a provision is associated with a Form/FormBenefit/Rider, the user selects a value for it. The value is either an arbitrary float, or or a selection from a set of Value Options defined for that provision in another table. The provision's definition determines which of those it gets.

For example, the provision "Policy Maximum Type" has four available value options ("Dollars", "Days", "Time Elapsed", "Weeks"). A given Form has been given the "Policy Maximum Type" provision, and the user selected the "Dollars" value for that provision on that particular form.

So we have a Form table, a Benefit table, and a Rider table. Those each have an ID, a name, and one or two other things.

**My question is a) how do I associate provisions with those three kinds of "owners", and b) how do I associate the two kinds of values with the selected provisions?**

I'm thinking of creating these two tables for the selection of provisions and their values:

```
SelectedProvision
    SelectedProvisionID     primary key not null
    -- Foreign key to Provision table. 
    ProvisionID             foreign key not null

    -- Exactly one of these three is not null
    FormID                  foreign key null
    FormBenefitID           foreign key null
    RiderID                 foreign key null

SelectedProvisionValue
    SelectedProvisionID     foreign key not null

    -- Exactly one of these two is not null
    ValueOptionID           foreign key null
    NumericValue            float null
```

I'm asking about the wisdom of the "exactly one of these X columns is not null" concept. Also, would it be good, bad, or indifferent to put NumericValue in the SelectedProvision table?

My other thought was to have one table to associate selected provisions with Forms, another for Form Benefit provisions, and another for Riders. It seems to me that providing values for them would become complicated.

Are there sensible alternatives to those two options?

Bonus question: Should SelectedProvisionValue have a surrogate key?

I've excluded the parts that seem to me to be irrelevant. I'm happy to go into more detail about the rest of the tables if needed.

Comment: @Mast Thanks very much.